# checking for next elements in list and if matched change and maintain the alternate order

Tags: python

`array a=[1,0,1,0,1,1]` the function should return 1 as after reversing the last element to 0
achieves alternate to `output=[1,0,1,0,1,0]`

`array a=[1,1,0,1,1]`the function should return 2 as after reversing the first and fifth element
achieves alternate to `output=[0,1,0,1,0]`

`array a =[0,1,1,0]` the function should return 2 as after reversing the first and second element
achieves alternate to `output=[1,0,1,0]`

`array a =[0,1,0]` the function should return 0 as the sequence is already present

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate() to produce an alternating pattern based on the first element value and count the elements that don't match the pattern using sum()

```
a=[1,0,1,0,1,1]
n = sum(b != i%2 for i,b in enumerate(a,a[0]))
print(n) # 1
```

For `[1,1,0,1,1]`, your expected result is 2 rather than 3 which indicates that you actually want to get the minimum number of changes (which you didn't specify explicitly so i'm guessing).

```
a=[1,1,0,1,1]
n = sum(b != i%2 for i,b in enumerate(a,a[0]))
n = min(n,len(a)-n)
print(n) # 2
```